# Strange behavior when converting a double to String in Java

Tags: java, android

I have a crash in my Android application coming from a strange behavior in a SQL query string construction. Here is the error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error: , while
compiling: SELECT [...], (0.6773931613745379*coslat*(coslng*0.9999276712889913
+sinlng*0.012027143*)+0.7356211694364222*sinlat) [...]
```

The errors comes precisely from here:  `sinlng*0.012027143*)` <== *) at the end

This string is builded by the following function:

```
public static String buildDistanceQuery(double latitude, double longitude) {
    final double coslat = Math.cos(MathUtils.deg2rad(latitude));
    final double sinlat = Math.sin(MathUtils.deg2rad(latitude));
    final double coslng = Math.cos(MathUtils.deg2rad(longitude));
    final double sinlng = Math.sin(MathUtils.deg2rad(longitude));
    return "(" + coslat + "*" + LocationColumns.COSLAT
            + "*(" + LocationColumns.COSLNG + "*" + coslng
            + "+" + LocationColumns.SINLNG + "*" + sinlng
            + ")+" + sinlat + "*" + LocationColumns.SINLAT 
            + ")";
}
```

As you can see, `LocationColumns.SINLNG + "*" + sinlng + ")"` becomes `sinlng*0.012027143*)` and I really don't see how this could be possible as sinlng is a double...

I cannot reproduce the problem, the crash comes from Android Market console and I do not have all the context. It is not a unique crash, I got multiple occurences.

I can try to use a StringBuilder() but I'm not sure it will correct the issue.

Do someone has a clue of how a double can generate a "*" when converted to String?

Comment: I doubt that could happen.  But I don't see your code matching up with the error message.  For example, your code appears to make two nested sets of parentheses while the error message only has one set.  Perhaps you're looking at a different piece of code, or an older version?

Comment: This is why parametrised SQL queries were invented.

Comment: can you log the exact returned string and paste it in your question too?

Comment: That code does *not* match the error message. That's *not* what is happening.

Comment: I made a mistake with the copy/paste of the error dump, this is not corrected.

Comment: @mcfinnigan has a great point - you wouldn't need to build these large string queries by hand, or at least not every time you needed to run them, if you parameterized the query string.  That could help here, perhaps helping you zero in on the exact problem.

Comment: @Rob I understand the point and I do use parametrised SQL queries, but in this case I have to build complex dynamic queries. I guess I could refactor my code but I still would like to understand how the star can appear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having planted some reporting inside my APK, I found the origin of the problem.

On the ZTE StarAddict, the result of:

```
final double sinlat = Math.sin(MathUtils.deg2rad(47.3572329));
```

is

```
0.0121*
```

I know this doesn't make sense, but this is the way it is. I guess this device is really flawed because other strings are being "translated":

```
final static String QUERY = "distance > ?";
```

becomes

```
"distance &gt; ?"
```

when used into the data provider.

I made some research on Google, but couldn't find anything specific.

For information, my application is active on 100K+ devices and only the ZTE StarAddict behaves like that. We can therefore exclude a mistake in my code.

If anyone has had the same problem than me, I'd be happy to hear for some clues.

Comment: same behavior with ZTE Blade. All string constants are converted to HTML (">"  becomes "&gt;")

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but there is a missing "(" just before the `coslng`, can you check?

**EDIT:** Thanks for fixing it, there is a way to just print or inspect the String made, to check if the * already appears there, or just after the Query is built? and maybe inspecting the double `sinlng` to se if it matches 0.012027143.

Not sure how this will help, but its a start :)

Comment: I can't to that because I can't reproduce the problem. The crashes come from external devices, automatically reported by Google Play  console. I have done a test unit on this function with all combination of value and never I get the "*" on the result.